# Click all links selected by query selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I'm getting an array of a tags by class selector and i want to click all these links

for example

`$('.sample')` returns

```
<a class="sample" href......</a>
<a class="sample" href......</a>
<a class="sample" href......</a>
```

when i call `$('.sample').click()` only clicks first element of array

Comment: It happens because once the first element is clicked your page starts unloading, then the linked page will load.

Comment: If you wank to click all the matched elements, you have to prevent the default action on the `$("a")` element. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

`.get(0)` will lets you target first element in the array:

```
 $('.sample').get(0).click();
```

Because when you do `$('.sample').click()` then first anchor element in the list will execute the `click()` and it will start to navigate to the specified `href` in the anchor, that is where document starts to unload and loads a new document in the window.

Comment: I think he wants to tagret all the matched elements.

Comment: @CliffBurton yes that is what i was about to update.

Answer (score 0):

Detect the siblings and then click them like this:

```js
$('a.sample').click(function(e) {
  var curLink=$(this);
  if (curLink.hasClass('clicked')) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      curLink.removeClass('clicked');
    },500);
    return false;
  } else {
    curLink.addClass('clicked');
    $('p').append("<br>Clicked: " + curLink.text() + ';');
    curLink.siblings().each(function() {
      $(this).click();
    });
  }
})
```

```css
.clicked{color:purple}
a{cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="sample">1st link</a><br>
<a class="sample">2nd link</a><br>
<a class="sample">3rd link</a>
<p></p>
```

The timeout will remove the class allowing you to reclick them again. You can also delay each click by placing a similar timeout inside of the each loop.

Comment: your anchors don't have any href attributes.

Comment: @Jai I did that on purpose, it's just to exemplify, he can put the hrefs he wants later.

Comment: You can add `onclick="alert()"` to the `a` elements to show your code is working

Comment: @Armfoot what could happen if you have hrefs?

Comment: @CliffBurton I hate those pop-ups sorry ;P I appended the link's text to the paragraph instead to show it's working.

Comment: @Jai depends on what he wants... If he has `#`'s in his hrefs for navigating/scrolling in the same page a new document is not loaded, as you said.